# How to read xml data and seperate it by tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read xml data and separate it by tag names so that I can save the values in variables for future use. But I am unable to read and filter the xml values. I need to read each value from the page given and seperate the tag values.
Following is my code-

I need to filter the data by CustomerID and find the particular email of the customer.
Can anyone help me please.

```
$.get("/read_xml.asp", function(XMLresponse) {


        var xmldata=XMLresponse;

          alert("Data Loaded: " + xmldata);
         // Customers
  alert(str.length);
    var str =xmldata;
    str = str.split('<CustomerID>');
    str[1] = str[1].split('</CustomerID>');
     alert(str[1]);
});
```

Comment: can you show your xml file

Comment: without seeing your xml, how can one help you?

Answer (score 0):

XML can be accessed like this (if it is valid):

```
var customerID = xmldata.getElementByTagName('CustomerID')[0].nodeValue;
```

like if it is a list:

```
for(var i = 0;i<xmldata.getElementByTagName('customer').length;i++){
  var customer = xmldata.getElementByTagName('customer')[i];
  var customerID = customer.getElementByTagName('CustomerID')[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, one must see your XML that you receive from that ajax call.

However, to traverse your document or to find elements with jquery is obvious.

```
$(xml).find('ParentElement').each(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('CustomerID');
 var title = $(this).find('CustomerTitle').text();
 var other = $(this).find('CustomerOther').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and then query the document like you would query the DOM using selectors.

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ), //create a document from the XML string
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ), //wrap the document in a jQuery object
    $title = $xml.find( "title" ); //find every title tags
```

*The example comes from the source I linked, but I added comments.*